# How can you generate a list containing a mix of consecutive numbers and letters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I go about generating the full list of possible iterations from at A1 AAA to Y999YYY? Would such as list be a struggle for my computer processor to generate?
What type of file would be the best to save such a list in order to be searched later?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the package `itertools`! It is awesome for generating combinations/permutations of anything.

```
import itertools
a = list(itertools.permutations([1,2,"A","B"])))
print(a)
```

The example mixes all of the numbers and letters together (I'm not totally clear on your problem statement). It should be pretty easy to make permutations/combinations of your letters, permutations/combinations of numbers, and mix them together in to the final result if you want them ordered together.

File types? That is a personal preference. `.json` would work well because you can save lists of lists of things.

```
import json

my_list = [['a', 'b','c'], ['b', 'a','c']]
with open("my_numbers.json", "w") as fp:
    json.dump(my_list, fp)
```